# Replace a single, specific NA value with a string

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I want to replace row 22907, column 1 with a string. The column is made up of factors. Column 1 in the dataframe is called geneID. I have tried the following:

```
df[22907,1] == 'CDEF'
```

But that gave the following error:

> Warning message:
>       In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "OKSM") :
>         invalid factor level, NA generated

I understand how to replace all NA's with a value, however I am only looking to replace this specific one.

Edit: Pretty sure this question is not a duplicate of the one linked - we got similar errors however the base question was different. This explains how to replace a single value in a dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We convert the column to `character` and then do the assignment

```
df[[1]] <- as.character(df[[1]])
df[22907,1] <- 'CDEF'
```

---

Or if we need to keep it as `factor`, create 'CDEF' as one of the `levels` of the column before the assignment

```
levels(df[[1]]) <- c(levels(df[[1]]), 'CDEF')
df[22907,1] <- 'CDEF'
df[22907, 1]
#[1] CDEF
#Levels: A B C D E CDEF
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(geneID = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 30000, replace = TRUE), 
            col2 = rnorm(30000))
df[22907, 1] <- NA
```

Comment: That is still returning an `NA`

Comment: @user1381852  It is because you already assigned it earlier.  try fresh from the original dataset

Comment: I had tried from the fresh data set. Trying adding it as one of the levels returned:

`Error in levels(df[[1]], "CDEF") : unused argument ("CDEF")`

Comment: @user1381852  I showed with a reproducible example.  It is working fine for me

Comment: I had forgotten to change the `==` to an `<-`
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the level `'CDEF'` first, then you can add it - factors require that the level exists before it can be assigned. Also `==` doesn't assign, use `=` or better yet `<-`. It's also good practice to call columns by their name rather than position (`df[22907, 'geneID']`).

```
levels(df[,1]) <- c(levels(df[,1]), 'CDEF')
df[22907,1] <- 'CDEF'
```

You can read more here about how to handle and think about factors: https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/12-supp-factors/

Comment: Wasn't there when I wrote it

Comment: Yes, and in that time I was writing my answer on a phone - there was no way to see what had happened on your answer. I haven't stolen your answer.